# Problem in showing MsSqlServer characters in laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, unicode, character-encoding, laravel-5.8

I have a MsSqlServer database with "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1256_CI_AS" Collation.

when I query to this database with Laravel, Persian characters like 'س' or 'گ' are shown like '\u064a' or '\u0634'.

how can I solve this problem?

I can't change the Collation of this database because it is currently used by another windows application.

Comment: Seems like you have a problem with your Laravel/PHP configuration. Those characters are `س` U+0633 "Seen" and `گ` U+06AF "Gaf", not `\u064a` and `\u0634` as Laravel/PHP reports. Are the sqlsrv/pdo_sqlsrv drivers [configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/non-system-locale-settings?view=sql-server-ver15) to use (Locale) LCID 0429 for Persian characters? Are you using at least ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server so as to get proper [character set support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/programming-guidelines#character-set-support)?

Comment: I have no configuration for sqlsrv/pdo_sqlsrv. I am using ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server